# Gradle error: Unexpected inputs: android.gms:play-services

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

In RunTime show error in Gradle the error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.

> Unexpected inputs: ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.0, file=/home/nawaf/AndroidStudioProjects/YugiohDeckBuilder/app/build/intermediates/transforms/profilers-transform/debug/43.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0, file=/home/nawaf/AndroidStudioProjects/YugiohDeckBuilder/app/build/intermediates/transforms/profilers-transform/debug/37.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.0, file=/home/nawaf/AndroidStudioProjects/YugiohDeckBuilder/app/build/intermediates/transforms/profilers-transform/debug/39.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.0.0, file=/home/nawaf/AndroidStudioProjects/YugiohDeckBuilder/app/build/intermediates/transforms/profilers-transform/debug/41.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0, file=/home/nawaf/AndroidStudioProjects/YugiohDeckBuilder/app/build/intermediates/transforms/profilers-transform/debug/36.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.0.0, file=/home/nawaf/AndroidStudioProjects/YugiohDeckBuilder/app/build/intermediates/transforms/profilers-transform/debug/42.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:9.0.0, file=/home/nawaf/AndroidStudioProjects/YugiohDeckBuilder/app/build/intermediates/transforms/profilers-transform/debug/38.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}, ImmutableJarInput{name=com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:9.0.0, file=/home/nawaf/AndroidStudioProjects/YugiohDeckBuilder/app/build/intermediates/transforms/profilers-transform/debug/40.jar, contentTypes=CLASSES, scopes=EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, status=REMOVED}

Gradle project-level:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    }
```

gradle app-level:

```
dependencies {
...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: did you try:- classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When I Add this line the problem solved:

```
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Thanks for all who response.

Comment: Nope.
Just Build -> Clean the project then Run again.

Answer (score 46):

It seems you have enable Instant Run in Android Studio.

1) Disable Instant Run from File -> Settings -> Instant Run
2) Clean Your Project
3) Run Your App

Comment: please let me know your target sdk version, compile sdk version and build tool version

Comment: i was having error due to facebooks shimmer library now i have solved this by rebuilding the project and invalidating cache.

Comment: somehow useful for me

Comment: Cleaning the project worked for me. Didn't have to disable instant run.

Comment: Cleaning the project was the solution in my case

Comment: Issue solved, but why do such difficult problems have easy solutions?

Answer (score 23):

Personally, `Build` => `Clean Project` and then `rebuilding` fixed it for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, at least if you work with Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Build Folder from Project->app->build and run your project.

Comment: this is similar to existing answer!