# Disabling instant run also disables breakpoints

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-debug, android-billing

I've recently ran into:

```
Unexpected scopes found in folder 'TrivialDrive_v2\mobile\build\intermediates\transforms\dexMerger\debug'. Required: EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES. Found: EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, PROJECT, SUB_PROJECTS
```

which has a fix suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814941/gradle-error-unexpected-inputs-android-gmsplay-services), which fixes it but now, the debugger won't stop on breakpoints (tested on the main activity's onCreate()).

Other [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890257/android-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexforrelease), mention adding:

```
multiDexEnabled true //important
```

to defaultConfig {} in the gradle build files. Already have that (ran into this earlier), but execution still doesn't stop at breakpoints. Initially it did. Why?

The app is [trivial drive v2](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/TrivialDrive_v2), extended with [predefined testing SKUs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing) (android.test.purchased, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the directories **.idea** and **.gradle** in the project's root directory, invalidating caches and restarting android worked (at least for now).